# delete not working (couldn't delete data after save)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular, stored-procedures

After press the save button

```
       var prod = [];
          for (i = 0; i < $("[name='pro_name']").length; i++) {
          var temp = {};
          temp["pro_name"] = $("[name=pro_name'] option:selected")[i].value;
          temp["model"] = $("[name=pro_model']")[i].value;
         

            if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i])) {
              if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i].id)) 
                temp["id"] = $scope.ext.prod[i].id;

            if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click))
                temp["delete_click"] = $scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click;
                          
        }

        prod.push(temp);
    }
```

so i tried to debug it, and it doesn't run the `temp["delete_click"] = $scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click;`

Store Procedure

```
                   begin
                   if @delete_click = 1 begin
                   DELETE FROM [db].[Prod_list]
                   WHERE [id]=@id
                   end
```

In my opinion something is wrong with the JS code, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While debugging check the values before *'if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i])) {'*

```
var click = $scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click;
var product = $scope.ext.prod[i];
var ext = $scope.ext;
var scope = $scope;

if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i])) {
  if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i].id)) 
    temp["id"] = $scope.ext.prod[i].id;

if (!isNull($scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click))
    temp["delete_click"] = $scope.ext.prod[i].delete_click;
}
```

Maybe some of these objects is reset on 'Save'.